# pygame sprite.Sprite classes

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

The only thing my script does (or used to do) is randomly place 50 black blocks and then one red one that follows the mouse, and when the red block hits a black one the black one is deleted, however I tried to change the script so that they would not be blocks and instead images, I'm new to pygame sprite groups, but here is my script:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)


screen_width = 1080
screen_height = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])

alien_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

Alien = ".../graphics/sprites/Alien.png"
Player = ".../graphics/sprites/Alien.png"

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

        self.image = pygame.image.load([image])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def Create():
        for i in range(50):
            alien = Enemy(Alien)

            alien.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width - 50)
            alien.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height - 50)

            alien_list.add(enemy)
            all_sprites.add(enemy)


player = Enemy(Player)
all_sprites.add(player)

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0


Enemy.Create()

while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.fill(white)

    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    player.rect.x = pos[0]
    player.rect.y = pos[1]

    enemys_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, True)

    for enemy in enemys_hit:
        score += 1
        print(score)

    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    clock.tick(30)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

and here is the error message:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\claude\Desktop\robotic\scripts\Game.py", line 39, in <module>
    player = Enemy(Player)
  File "C:\Users\claude\Desktop\robotic\scripts\Game.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load([image])
pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
>>>
```

thanks for your time and help

Comment: One little comment, you don't need to say `while done == False:` I think the preferred approach is to use `while not done`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `[]` brackets around `image` in `load`. It should be:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
```

From the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load):

```
pygame.image.load()
#load new image from a file

load(filename) -> Surface
load(fileobj, namehint=””) -> Surface
```

By wrapping `image` in brackets, as `[image]`, you're making a `list`, and passing that as the filename. But `pygame.image.load()` expects a filename, not a list of filenames

Comment: Couldn't open .../graphics/sprites/Alien.png

Comment: Make sure the image is in the correct path relative to your working directory (`os.getcwd()`). Try putting the image there directly and not passing a directory. Or pass the *absolute* path to its location on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You has many errors.

How to say previously

```
self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
```

and change enemy with alien

```
alien_list.add(alien)
    all_sprites.add(alien)
```

And change enemy_list by alien_list
enemys_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, alien_list, True)

and your code works fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8cEd.png)